# How to represent a recursive function with a Flow Chart?

Tags: recursion, flowchart

I need to represent a recursive function on a flow chart. 
My problem is that I don't know how to indicate that the function may call itself over multiple elements at a time (think for example to a function which scans graphs).
Someone has any suggestion?

Comment: Be alert: I'll give a definite canonical answer to your question soon (first for primitive recursive functions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a flow chart, you don't normally add multiple invocations for things like loops, you would just indicate that the code may be repetitively called until a condition is met. So, for a recursive function, it would be similar - the base case is a regular step and the recursive step is the same as loop. See [this](http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/~frans/OldLectures/COMP101/week9/recursion.html) for an example.

Comment: This is only really only effective for tail recursion. Otherwise you need to combine results from the recursive call and you just bumped into the limits of flow charts.